# how to costume title single page

Tags: themes, title

how to costume title single page on wordpress , 
for example in this picture , i want to change/add text "Theme Preview" ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use "the_title" filter for this.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_title

```
add_filter('the_title','callbackfunction');
function callbackfunction($data){
   global $post;
   $new_title = "new page title"; //You can set dynamic title from $post
   return $new_title;
}
```

If you just want to change the site title you can do this in the backend itself

**"Settings->General->Site Title"**

Comment: `the_title` is the post/page title, and would not affect the "Theme Review" part of the title.